# Unable to resume upgrade from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10 after not enough free disk space error

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.10

I was updating Ubuntu from 20.04 to 20.10 and I got an error because I did not have enough disk space, it avorted the upgrade.

I made space for the upgrade, I opened again the software update manager and the upgrade to 20.10 was still available, but hitting the upgrade button just closed the software update manager.

I tried with `sudo do-release-upgrade` and it said:

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

But doing apt upgrade showed not pending updates:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I resume the upgrade?

Comment: Try `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`.

Comment: Above comment + you do need to make quite a bit of space - more than it tells you. The update has to download all the packages, extract and install them; and only then will it start removing the installers. If anything, make at least double the space you need if you can as headroom.

Edit: you also may need to run `apt autoremove` after the release upgrade as a lot of stuff will still be there.

Comment: I did free 40 GB, that should be more than enough. And I did `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but it says that the system is already up to date, there are no updates available. Also `apt autoremove` shows nothing. There are no broken packages or anything because the update did never start. I guess this is a bug with the upgrade system so I will report it.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1286218/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update`

Comment: I checked more carefully and `sudo apt update` did show qtcam stuck in xenial, I did update the repo to bionic and then it found updates fine, I did run the updates. After updating that, the upgrade UI was still not working but the `sudo do-release-upgrade` seem to be working.

Comment: Since this a Q&A site, I'd encourage you to post an answer instead of appending it in question under solution. You can mark your answer as accepted after 48 hours.

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

`sudo apt upgrade` did not show anything, but `sudo apt update` did show a package that was kept back.

It was qtcam because the repo was stuck on xenial, I updated the repo to use bionic and I updated packages normally.

After that the upgrade UI was still not working but using `sudo do-release-upgrade` did work and I could upgrade to Ubuntu 20.10 normally.